# How can I compare an array of structs to see which elements are different?

Tags: swift, ios8

I have two arrays of structs which contains a couple doubles that I want to compare.

I want to compare each space of the older array to the newer, and see which indexes contain structs in which both doubles match, and remove them from the newer of the two arrays. I want the end result to be an array with only the sets of doubles that are not included in the first array. In other words, both arrays have different sets.

I originally tried iterating through each index one at a time, but removing an index messes up the loop. So I tried creating a third array to add the ones that aren't the same, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to efficiently find out which are different.

Are there any quick Swift solutions that anyone knows of that could help with this problem efficiently?

This is the code I have so far, but I'm sort of stuck here because the result will be nothing near what I'm looking for...

```
if userPosts.count == 0 {
        userPosts = newArrayOfUserPosts
    }
    if newArrayOfUserPosts.count > 0 {
        for currentCount in 0...userPosts.count - 1 {

            for eachElement in 0...newArrayOfUserPosts.count - 1 {

                if newArrayOfUserPosts[eachElement].postLatitude != userPosts[currentCount].postLatitude && newArrayOfUserPosts[eachElement].postLongitude != userPosts[currentCount].postLongitude {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It isn't completely clear what you're trying to do. Are you expecting the first parts of both arrays to be the same, and then start diverging at the end? This would only be the case if the arrays are in the same order.

Does the order matter? What if the 2 arrays contain the same elements but in different order? Is that a match? Does the code to compare the elements to see if they are equal work, or does that give you a compiler error? (You probably have to make your struct conform to the equatable protocol so you can use == and != to compare them.)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use a `Set` and the `subtract` method to get the difference in the arrays. Here's an example using `Set<Int>`:

```
let oldArray = [0, 2, 7, 5, 10]
let newArray = [0, 2, 7, 5, 10, 11, 8, 20]

let oldSet = Set(oldArray)
let newSet = Set(newArray)

Array(newSet.subtract(oldSet)) // [20, 11, 8]
```

Or if you wanted it on one line:

```
Array(Set(newArray).subtract(Set(oldArray))) // [20, 11, 8]
```

For this to work you'll need to make your struct conform to `Hashable`.

For more information on `Set` have a look at *[The Swift Programming Guide: Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

```
let firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

let secondArray = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

secondArray.filter{!contains(firstArray, $0)} //[7, 8]
```

This takes the second array, and removes everything that's in the first array. This only works on things that are Equatable, though. To make your struct Equatable on some variable in it, you have to implement ==, based on what you think makes two structs the same. Here's an example:

```
struct Person : Equatable {
  let name: String
  let age: Int
}

func == (leftHandSide: Person, rightHandSide: Person) -> Bool {
  return leftHandSide.name == rightHandSide.name
}
```

There's a struct, Person. In it, you can have a person's name, and their age. We can decide to identify people based on their name, which is why our == function works on .name.

Here's how it would work with the filtering:

```
let youngBarry = Person(name: "Barry", age: 25)
let joanna = Person(name: "Joanna", age: 32)
let oldBarry = Person(name: "Barry", age: 44)

let firstArray = [youngBarry]

let secondArray = [oldBarry, joanna]

let filteredSecondArray = secondArray.filter{!contains(firstArray, $0)} //Joanna
```

When we want to remove things from the second array that are in the first array, our == function looks at oldBarry and youngBarry, and decides that they're the same, so doesn't include oldBarry in the second.

Now, if you wanted to do more complicated or variable behaviour with your removing, you still can, because "contains" can take a closure. Here's the same code as above, but without == implemented:

```
let filteredSecondArray = secondArray.filter{
  secondArrayElement in

  !contains(firstArray) {

    firstArrayElement in

    return secondArrayElement.name == firstArrayElement.name

  }

}
```

Your use case looks like it's more suited to implementing Equatable, though. Here's how you would do that.:

```
extension YourStruct : Equatable {}

func == (lhs: YourStruct, rhs: YourStruct) -> Bool {
  return lhs.postLatitude == rhs.postLatitude && lhs.postLongitude == rhs.postLongitude
}
```

And then just:

```
let filteredNewArrayOfUserPosts = newArrayOfUserPosts.filter{!contains(userPosts, $0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Equatable to your struct.

```
struct Refinement: Equatable {
    let key: String
    var value: String
}
```

If you want to add own condition then add

```
func == (leftHandSide: Refinement, rightHandSide: Refinement) -> Bool {
    return (leftHandSide.key == rightHandSide.key) && (leftHandSide.value == rightHandSide.value)
}
```

Or else it will check all values in struct by default.

Then check the array by normal **==**

```
if expectedFacetRefinements == facetRefinements {
    print("true")
} else {
    print("false")
}
```